Identify cartoon with little animals looking for their family who was at a reserve
This cartoon I'm looking for was about a group of little animals.
I don't remember what species they were, but they were all the same species.
I'm pretty sure they were all siblings, and were looking for their parents who were at a reserve.
There's two things I remember clearly:
1) The critters didn't know what cars were. Every time they saw one, they thought it was a monster that ate humans only to spit them out later (People getting in and out the car). If I recall correctly, they were deeply afraid of the "monsters."
2) One of the critters was the smartest of them all, a nerd. I don't remember his real name, but his initials were "A.J." Every time the others called him "A.J.", he got angry and yelled: "Don't call me A.J!" and asked to be called by his name.
I watched it on the 90's; I don't know where it is from, though, as I watched it dubbed on Spanish.
